# how to Display the response data after fetch in reactjs

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, fetch, next.js

I am trying to get the json data using fetch() method and display it over a webpage using reactjs. As of now the following code prints the data in console but i need the same kind of output over the webpage. How to display it on the page?

```
import React from 'react';


export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/testing2`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log('This is your data', data));
  }
  render() {
    return<h1>my Component has Mounted, Check the browser 'console' </h1>;
  }

}
```

console output(need this output over the webpage and also need to be define it as a const/let/var/ so that i can access the key-values for further purpose):

This is your data (22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PersonList class, define a state and update the state upon fetching persons data like this and then render the data,

```
export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
    state = {
       persons: [],
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/testing2`).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
          console.log('This is your data', data)
          this.setState({ persons: [...data]});
       });
    }

    render() {
       return (
           <>
               <h1>my Component has Mounted, Check the browser 'console' </h1>
               {this.state.persons.length && this.state.persons.map((person) => <li>{JSON.stringify(person)}</li>)}
           </>
       );
    }

}
```

Comment: How can we use only the key "overallstatus" . Because on using this key i have to write an if else condition. condition will be like is (overallstatus === success) it should return a "success!!" or else "failed" messages.

Comment: To answer that we need some more information, is the OverAllStatus object always the last item of the array?

Comment: Thanks @sabbir.alam!!. Got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be the following. This will give you a [key: value] pair in each index of the array.

```
export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
        state = {
           persons: [],
        }
        componentDidMount() {
           fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/testing2`).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
              console.log('This is your data', data)
              let mydata = [];
              data.map(row=>{
                Object.keys(row).map(key=>{
                  mydata.push({key,value:row[key]})
                })
              })
              this.setState({ persons: mydata });
           });
        }
        render() {
           return (
               <>
                   <h1>my Component has Mounted, Check the browser 'console' </h1>
                   <ul>
                   {this.state.persons.length && this.state.persons.map((person) => <li>Key is {person.key} and value is {person.value}</li>)}
                   </ul>
               </>
           );
        }

    }
```

An alternate approach is to store key-value pairs in a persons object and then access it with any key you need. This assumes you will have unique keys in every object of the data returned by the API.

```
export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
        state = {
           persons: {},
        }
        componentDidMount() {
           fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/testing2`).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
              console.log('This is your data', data)
              let mydata = {};
              data.map(row=>{
                Object.keys(row).map(key=>{
                  mydata[key] = row[key]
                })
              })
              this.setState({ persons: mydata });
           });
        }
        render() {
           return (
               <>
                   <h1>my Component has Mounted, Check the browser 'console' </h1>
                   <ul>
                   {Object.keys(this.state.persons).map((key) => <li>Key is {key} and value is {this.state.persons[key]}</li>)}
                   </ul>
               </>
           );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response SaachiTech. On using this code I am getting the following error

Comment: Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: mydata.push is not a function

Comment: how can i return the value of one particular key like "OverAllStatus" ?

Comment: Added another approach. You can merge them as per your requirement or use any one of them.

Comment: `render() {
       return (
           <>
               <h1>my Component has Mounted, Check the browser 'console' </h1>
               <ul>
               {this.state.persons.length && this.state.persons.find(function(person) { return person.Key == "OverAllStatus"})}
               </ul>
           </>
       );
    }
`

Comment: Yeah but it will run on every render so second approach I posted will work in your case as you can directly access without finding

Comment: So from second approach you can access any key like this `this.state.persons.OverAllStatus`

Comment: You can remove the mapping and add your logic for UI. For example `<li>OverAllStatus:{this.state.persons.OverAllStatus}</li>`

Comment: how to iterate through the json object which looks like {"scope":"abcdefg","access_token":"12345","refresh_token":"12345tfr","expires_in":1799,"token_type":"Bearer"} on using the above codes it gives me Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: If it’s already object, you can directly save it to state and access it with key. Mapping is not requested